# Firebase Cloud Messaging icon too small

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send messages to my angular webapp. Sending and receiving messages works fine. The notification looks as follows:

[image]

I have the problem that I haven't found a way yet to display a larger icon and to set the text color to anything else than black. I would like to have it as in the row above.

I send the following json to firebase:

```
{ 
    "notification": 
    {
        "title": "POSTMAN", 
        "body": "Message from postman", 
        "icon": "https://placeimg.com/250/250/nature",
        "click_action" : "https://angularfirebase.com"

    },
    "to" : "fMhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwZ9"

}
```